Re-Launch application from Playstore
I have a React Native Expo application which checks third party application installation, if the application is installed it move ahead but if not it redirects user to playstore to download the application. However after the download the user has to move back to the application themselves. I want a solution where once application is installed the user should automatically move back to the main application.
I have added package and app state to check the application installed or not.
Linking.openURL('playstoreURL');
Used the above code to open playstore for the specific package installation.

This question is similar to: Redirect user after installing the app with a given link. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

firebase dynamic link is deprecated what to use now?
